# What does "Independent visual approach" mean, at airports with parallel runways?

Tags: approach, parallel-runways

I have read that some airports, with parallel runways, use this procedure - INDEPENDENT VISUAL APPROACHES, but I could not understand very well the meaning, and for this reason, the purpose. Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Consider an airport with only one runway. In order to keep aircraft safely apart (and to give them time to exit the runway), all aircraft must be separated by some distance as they are on final approach.

```
RWY 27  ————— *   *   * <-- acft 3NM in trail
```

If an airport has two parallel runways, now you can have aircraft landing on both of them. But if the runways are too close together you need to worry not just about spacing in line to each runway on its own—you also need to worry about spacing side-to-side with aircraft approaching the other runway. You may have to have **dependent approaches** where the position of an aircraft on final to one runway determines the position of an aircraft on final to the other. For example, you may need to ensure that aircraft are staggered on the finals with one mile of diagonal separation:

```
RWY 27R ————— *   *   * <-- acft 3NM in trail
               \ / \ /  <-- 1NM diagonal separation
RWY 27L —————   *   *
```

But if the runways are far enough apart, or if you have the correct procedures in place, you can run **independent approaches**. That means each aircraft on final is only a factor for the aircraft also on the same final—they can be side-to-side with aircraft on the parallel final.

```
RWY 27R ————— *   *   * <-- acft 3NM in trail
               

RWY 27L ————— *   *   *
```

This concept can apply to instrument approaches and/or visual approaches depending on how the local aviation authority has set out its rules.

Comment: Heartwarming to see that ascii art remains alive and well.

Comment: @randomhead: Thanks a million!